Need spring web 5.3.41 version
In my project found some vulnerabilities . As per resolution need to use spring web 5.3.41 which is support by java 8. But as verified did not found this version. Is this version is released / plan to release this in coming days ....
If we use higher version like 6.0.23 getting below error..
org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

No it isn't. 5.3.39 is the latest OSS version, if you want fixes on that you need to pay for the commercial extented support. So either do a proper upgrade including an update to JDK 17 (or up) or pay the license fee.

Spring version 5.3.39 is the last OSS support version, support ended as of august of 2024. If  you want support after that version you need to get enterprise support.
So no that version will never be released to the public.
I would suggest a proper upgrade to Spring 6.2 including upgrading the JDK. Java 8 is quite old and dated and deserves to be upgraded to JDK17 at least.
